# Ela "fá-los bem", ou ela "faze-os" bem?

Tags: uso-de-palavras

Qual a forma (mais) correta?

- Ela **fá-los** bem.
- Ela **faze-os** bem.

Answer (score 5):

Ela **fá-los** (*faz* + *os*) bem.

A regra geral é a de que às formas verbais terminadas em *s*/*z*/*r* são apostas as variantes *lo*/*la*/*los*/*las* dos clíticos *o*/*a*/*os*/*as* e que a terminação cai. O acento é o necessário para manter a vogal final.

A única exceção é mesmo o verbo querer, que tem de facto *quere-os* para *quer* + *os*. *Qué-los* seria a forma esperada pela regra acima — é uma forma permitida, pouco usada. A mesma exceção não pode ser aplicada ao verbo *fazer*, por isso temos para o presente:

*faço-os* / *faze-los* / *fá-los* / *fazemo-los* / *fazei-los* / *fazem-nos*

[Tabela de conjugação completa de *fazer* + *os*](http://lxcenter.di.fc.ul.pt/services/online_conj/cgi-bin/flex.cgi?lemma=fazer&type=tran&clitic1=accus&clitic1a_person=3&clitic1a_number=P&clitic1a_gender=M&lang=pt)

Answer (score 0):

O correto seria: **fá-los**

Segundo o site [TodaMateria](https://www.todamateria.com.br/pronomes-obliquos/):

> - Os pronomes me, te, nos, vos e se são empregados como objetos direto ou indireto: Exemplos: Eles me respeitam. (respeitar alguém - objeto direto) ou Entregaram-te o documento ontem. (entregar a alguém - objeto indireto).
> - Os pronomes o, a, os e as são empregados como objetos diretos. Exemplo: Fechou-a e saiu. (fechou algo - objeto direto).
>     os pronomes lhe e lhes são empregados como objetos indiretos. Exemplo: Devolverei se estas coisas pertencerem-lhes. (pertencer a alguém - objeto indireto)
>
> Quando seguidos de verbos que terminam em –z, -s ou –r, os pronomes o, a, os, as assumem as formas lo, la, los, las. Neste caso, a terminação verbal é retirada.
>
> Exemplos:
>
> - **faz + o = fá-lo**
> - comes + os = comê-los
> - estudar + a = estudá-la

Comment: "comes + os" é "come-los", não "comê-los". Comê-los é "comer + os"

Comment: Também não gosto de: 1. "me respeitam" mas "Entregaram-te" (ou "me respeitam" e "te entregaram", ou "respeitam-me" e "entregaram-te"); 2. "pertencerem-lhes" (devia ser "lhes pertencerem"... ou será que isto é válido no Brasil?).

Comment: no Brasil, raramento usamos o pronome no final das palavras. Seria na maioria das vezes: me respeitam, me entragaram e assim por diante... Eu vivo em Lisboa agora e noto a diferença...

Answer (score -1):

No Brasil, "os faz", pra não soar estranho e até não confundir com outras palavras (como «falo»).